# C programming : Stackoverflow is a cause of abrupt termination

Tags: c

In case of stack overflow in C programming, why do we tell it abrupt termination of   loop. Shack-overflow is not a cause of infinite looping. But causing abrupt termination, though we cannot see, where is it terminating.
right??
Say for this program, it is causing a stack overflow but not a case of infinite looping

```
int foo(int val) {
    int x=0;
    while(val > 0) {
        x = x + foo(val--);
    }
    return val;
}
```

But why we cannot say it as an infinite looping??and why is it saying as abrupt termination??

Comment: `foo` would never terminate. If you add a print statement to print `val` before the loop you'll see why. And I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want differentiation between abrupt termination and infinite looping ,when there is a stack overflow of a C program

Comment: Where did you find this code? It makes no sense.

Comment: here:https://gateoverflow.in/118319/gate2017-1-36

Comment: I cannot see. It requires login.

Comment: It is an exam question.

Comment: A function that calls itself infinitely will ultimately crash because of stack overflow. So I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: And if the program crashes, then can we say, it is abruptly terminated. This termination is because OS has no more space. Can we say like this??

Comment: check here : options are like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gate-gate-cs-2017-set-1-question-39/

Comment: So, here can we say infinite looping causing abrupt termination?? and actually no difference between these two??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is recursion, every call of the function foo() will increase the stack. And as we know the loop never ends so at some point stack will increase so much that the OS will terminate the code and give stack-overflow error.

Comment: why not infinite looping??

Comment: may be you get infinite looping if you replace inner foo() and make some changing like this:
int foo(int val) {
    int x=0;
    while(1) {
        x = x + 1;
    }
    return val;
}